# Enable local network access during iOS UI test in iOS14

Tags: ios, testing, networking, permissions, xctest

We are building an iOS app that connects to a device using Bluetooth. To test unhappy flow scenarios for this app, we'd like to power cycle the device we are connecting to by using an IoT power switch that connects to the local network using WiFi (a Shelly Plug-S).

In my test code on iOS13, I was able to do a local HTTP call to the IP address of the power switch and trigger a power cycle using its REST interface. In iOS 14 this is no longer possible, probably due to new restrictions regarding local network usage without permissions (see: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10110/).

When running the test and trying a local network call to the power switch in iOS14, I get the following error:

```
Task <D206B326-1820-43CA-A54C-5B470B4F1A79>.<2> finished with error [-1009] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009 "The internet connection appears to be offline." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=50, NSUnderlyingError=0x2833f34b0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1009 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=50, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <D206B326-1820-43CA-A54C-5B470B4F1A79>.<2>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
"LocalDataTask <D206B326-1820-43CA-A54C-5B470B4F1A79>.<2>"), NSLocalizedDescription=The internet connection appears to be offline., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://192.168.22.57/relay/0?turn=on, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://192.168.22.57/relay/0?turn=on, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}
```

An external network call (to google.com) works just fine in the test.

I have tried fixing this by adding the following entries to the Info.plist of my UI test target:

```
<key>NSLocalNetworkUsageDescription</key>
<string>Local network access is needed for tests</string>
<key>NSBonjourServices</key>
<array>
    <string>_http._tcp</string>
</array>
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

However, this has no effect.

I have also tried adding these entries to the Info.plist of my app target to see if that makes a difference, but it doesn't. I'd also rather not add these entries to my app's Info.plist, because the app does not need local network access. Only the test does.

Does anyone know how to enable local network access during an iOS UI test in iOS14?

Comment: Hey! Did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: I am having a similar issue. have you found a solution?

Comment: I also started a topic about this on Apple's dev forums, there have been a few responses there that might be worth checking out: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/668729